# Is it feasible for a general purpose programming language to not have a heap?

Tags: heap-memory, programming-languages

I'm looking into creating a programming language. What I'm wondering is, in a language that contains a reference-like construct, is it feasible to not have a new/malloc operator? That is, all variables are stored either on the stack somewhere or are statically allocated.

The idea is that you get better type safety, as well as "free garbage collection" without actually having a garbage collector.

I'm not familiar with too many scripting languages, so if one already does this, feel free to point it out.

(Dynamic / unknown size data structures would be handled by a dynamic list structure, which would be handled (obviously) on the heap, behind the user's back.)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you have in mind here. How would your proposed language handle, say, a function creating an array and returning a reference to it? Where should that array be allocated if not on the stack? Also I don't see how you get around the need for garbage collection if you still put objects of unknown size into a "dynamic list" on the heap.

Comment: Functions would not create an array and return a reference. The array would have to be created by the calling function. Also, objects in a dynamic list would necessarily be of known size.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my second question. You said "Dynamic / unknown size data structures would be handled by a dynamic list structure". I just wanted to know how that would get around the need for garbage collection. You'd still need to remove the objects from the list at some point - or the memory would be leaked.

Comment: This would really help get rid of annoying memory/resource leak problems, and we could use patterns like RAII too!

Answer (score 2):

Fortran was always quite a "general purpose" language, but it had no support for any kind of a dynamic memory allocation out of the box.

A usual practice was to allocate a big array statically and simulate your own memory management on top of it.

If a way to get rid of both GC and a manual memory management is what you're looking for, then [region analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management) can help, but only in few specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

[Region-based memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management) was one approach for not having a heap managed in the traditional sense.  This manifested in languages like [FX](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/specpub.php?id=975) and [MLKit](http://www.itu.dk/research/mlkit/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement at all that you absolutely have to implement a stack, or a heap. C does not specify a stack either, for example. In fact, in many languages you don't even need to care, you just specify that the implementation (a compiler, an interpret, or whatever) to make room for a variable, and perhaps for how long.

Your language's interpreter (assuming one) could do `int main(void) { char memory[1048576]; run_script_from_stdin_using(memory); }`. You could even call mmap(2) to get an anonymous block of memory and use that to stash your variables in. It just does not matter where objects live, and that stack/heap are terms that have questionable meaning given they are often interchangeable.

Comment: While all that is true (except that the terms stack and heap are interchangeable - not sure what you mean by that), I don't think it helps the OP very much. As I understood it his intent was to get around the need for garbage collection or manual memory management. If you store objects into a global array or `mmap`ed memory, you still need to remove them eventually, if you don't want them to leak. Of course you can just say "we have enough memory, let's let the objects lie around until the program terminates", but you could do that just as easily on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate objects on the stack if you know they won't be referenced after the method terminates. This means, the object is used solely withing the method (e.g. a temp object), or use solely in method resulting from nested invocations. This is however a severe restriction. There are some dynamic optimizations that go in this direction though (at least optimization of temp object). You could maybe have a static checking mechanism that enforces this restriction, or possibly distinguish between heap and stack objects with types...